# Server on AWS Beanstalk running at half speed

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

For some odd reason, when I run the server locally, I get a stable `59fps`. But when I upload to AWS, it gives me less than half the speed - to `24fps`

I've also tried using `setInterval()`, but it does the same thing

Any ideas?

```
var previousTick = 0;
//Update LOBBIES
function gameLoop(){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    if(previousTick + Math.floor(1000/settings.cps) < now){
        previousTick = now;
        
        checkCPS();
        
        var pack = {
            server: {
                cps: cpsSave
            }
        };
        
        for(var L in LOBBY_LIST){
            var lobby = LOBBY_LIST[L].title;
            
            pack.players = Player.update(lobby);
            
            for(var S in SOCKET_LIST){
                var user = SOCKET_LIST[S];
                if(user.lobby == lobby){
                    user.emit('refresh', pack);
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    if(now - previousTick < Math.floor(1000/settings.cps) - 16){
        setTimeout(gameLoop, 1);//sloppy timer
    }
    else {
        setImmediate(gameLoop);//ultra accurate method
    }
}

gameLoop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was, I was using the instance `t2.micro`, once I switched to `t2.small` it started working normal